# Magento 2 production deployment: which commands?

Tags: magento2, deployment

I am currently in the process of creating a Magallanes production environment for release deployments on a server.

However, I am unsure which commands actually need to be executed and in which order. Currently I execute the following:

- `composer install`
- copy/symlink `app/etc/config.php` & `app/etc/env.php`
- custom command to set the correct domain in `core_config_data` table
- `app:config:import`
- `setup:upgrade`
- `deploy:mode:set production`
- `setup:static-content:deploy …`

Is there anything I am missing or should anything be executed in another order for a clean deployment?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to execute this : `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production`, by doing this Magento clear the contents of following directories:

```
var/cache
var/di
var/generation
var/view_preprocessed
pub/static
```

I let you see the [Magento mode DevDocs.](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-mode.html)

Comment: This is not enough. If I only use `deploy:mode:set production` during the magephp deployment procedure, I get the following error in the front end: `The configuration file has changed. Run app:config:import or setup:upgrade command to synchronize configuration.`

Comment: According to the Magento dev doc, you don't need that, try to execute that command so `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Comment: But that is my question ;). See above: I am asking which commands I have to execute in which order. So what should it be now?

Comment: the is no problem if you execute `bin/magento setup:upgrade` before or after the `deploy` command so 1. `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production` 2. `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` also if you want `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: `setup:static-content:deploy` is not necessary, this is done by `deploy:mode:set production`. I have the following order which seems to work now: https://pastebin.com/3QyVWzX1 However I still wonder is this is the correct way to do. I think the fact that I have to manually change the website domain in the database makes the `app:config:import` necessary.

Comment: Maybe, I've never had this import case

Comment: Are you sure `setup:upgrade` is not needed at all? What if new modules got installed that contain database schema updates or installs. This would be done only in `setup:upgrade`, right?